# Mixed use of Parallel and subprocess in Python3, causing lower CPU efficiency over time?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess

I am running a Python3 script which contains 3 main functions. `somefunction()` use subprocess to get result from another program "eval"; `foo()` applies Parallel on `somefunction()`; `bar()` contains a for loop calling `foo()` repeatedly.

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import subprocess

class Foobar:
    def somefunction(self, i):
        cmdline = '~/path/eval ' + 'i' # eval is an executable
        output = subprocess.check_output(cmdline, shell=True)
        return output

    def foo(self):
        # Parallel 
        num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        list = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(self.somefunction)(i) for i in somerange)

    def bar(self):
        for i in range(1000):
           self.foo()

result = Foobar()
result.bar()
```

I am running this on a Google compute VM instance with 10vCPU. At the beginning, all 10 CPUs are running, and it takes 1 min to run `foo()`. However, as time goes by, the number of running CPUs becomes less and less, as a consequence, it takes 5+ mins to run `foo()`.

I think the problem is caused somehow by the mixed use of `subprocess` and `Parallel`, I tried to exclude `subprocess` by changing the `somefunction()` as follows and the problem was gone.

```
    def somefunction(self, i):
        for k in range(100000):
            k += 1
        return k
```

What is happening in the original code? What is the elegant way to reconstruct this?

Comment: After like half an hour (about 15 times of running the foo()), eventually only one CPU is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by changing multiprocessing to multithreading:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(self.somefunction)(i) for i in somerange)
```

to

```
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores, prefer="threads")(delayed(self.somefunction)(i) for i in somerange)
```